# Word Dictionary Library AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, dictionary, cpu-word

1) Are there any public libraries/SWCs built for AS3 that includes a list of words, their definitions as well as functions to search for words from?

2) If not, I've been looking on the web for public dictionary of words. Is there one "best" word list? One that updates when new words are added?

Also, i found a word list that didn't have color but had colour - I'd prefer to have the lists that have both since they both are acceptable.

1. And also if there isn't any as3 libraries that include built in word lists, if I were to load one in locally through my code, what would be the best way of storing?

I was thinking that just looping through all the words in the word list and add them as an element to a `Dictionary` object - a key being the word string and value maybe being the definition. Lookups would be O(1) right? The reason why I'm asking is because I know some people have built trees but wouldn't that take time to traverse?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash tables are very suited for this.
The Dictionary object in flash is somewhat a hash table. But instead just accepts anything as a key.

There is this http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/squiggly/
Not sure what it can do though.

Just a notification:
While Color and Colour are both correct, the "correct" word is still different for each country. ( US - UK ).